# bash: redirect the stderr/stdout of a running process?

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I have a running process running in a bash terminal that is printing some prompt, and I would like to send it to the background with the stderr/stdout prompt that is printing either redirected to /dev/null or somewhere else, so that I can keep using that terminal for something else, but not have to kill the process and restart it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Redirect STDERR / STDOUT of a process AFTER it's been started, using command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin)

Comment: I don't feel like repeating what's in the above mentioned Q/A, but if you found a solution for your problem feel free to post this as an answer here :)

Comment: Like so? > `process_name >> /dev/null` &

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to stdin of a running bash shell?](https://superuser.com/questions/403148/how-to-redirect-to-stdin-of-a-running-bash-shell)