# How to redirect to stdin of a running bash shell?

Tags: bash, redirection

Theoreticly, if I know the pid of the bash shell which is running, I can run a cat whose stdout is redirected to the stdin of that shell. It seems to be as if I type something on that shell. Unfortunately, there WILL be stream coming from cat, BUT WILL NOT make the shell act properly (the entered command from cat will not be executed by bash).

Open a terminal:

```
ps -ef | grep bash
ymf       4906  4887  0 16:19 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
```

On another terminal:

```
cat 1> /proc/4906/fd/0
echo 'hello!'
```

Why?

Comment: Did you send the 'Return' key, too? As that would be needed to end a command.

Comment: @boretom Of course I did.

Comment: Yes, I see, interesting question. The input to bash seems to be redirected to the stdout. Try running a command like `top` and you'll see that the stdin is just add somewhere to the output. My guess is that since the shell is started as an interactive shell it won't accept commands from stdin. But that's pure speculation.

Comment: While I'm no guru here, I think what you do is writing to the terminal emulator, and not to the process in question. IE you write to the right pipe junction, but it winds up in the wrong of the two pipes.

Comment: @boretom try `ls -l /proc/PID/fd/`. 0, 1, 2 are all redirected to `/dev/pts/TERM_NUMER` No matter whether it accepts commands from stdin, I'm sure of that fd0 is for input and I've already redirect the output of cat to it.

Comment: @Eroen sorry, I don't quite catch your words which wrote "winds up in the wrong of the two pipes". (My English is rather poor... XD)

Comment: More likely, I explained poorly. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5380763/1057848). `/proc/$pid/fd/0` gives terminal (or pipe or whatever) input when a process reads from it. In this case it is a symlink to a tty. when the process reads from the tty (via `../fd/0`) it gets what was inputed in the tty. When you write to the tty, via the same file, the data is printed in the tty, not sent as input to the process.

Comment: @Eroen What's difference between typing in tty and redirecting stream to its stdin(fd0) ?

Comment: When you type into a tty, the data can be read by a process from `/dev/pts/xx`. (The data is also usually echoed to screen, as part of the tty emulation). This is the common way to have user input to a process.

Comment: If you start a shell in a terminal, it's fd0 (and 1 and 2) is a symlink to a tty (the same one). When you write to a tty, the data is shown in that tty. This is the common way to have output to a user from a process.

Comment: Essentially equivalent to [Ask a running bash (interactive) to run a command from outside](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7370538/3960947) (on SO).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm tired of the "one paragraph only" limit in comments =)

If you start a shell `sh`, and get the pid `$pid` you can find the file descriptors as you describe. An example:

```
$ ls -l /proc/29201/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 eroen users 64 Mar 22 15:52 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 eroen users 64 Mar 22 15:52 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 eroen users 64 Mar 22 15:52 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 eroen users 64 Mar 22 15:52 255 -> /dev/pts/2
```

You will notice that `1`, `2` and `3` are all symlinks to the same tty (a chardev). In other words, the input to the process is read from the same device node as the outputs are written to.

When you attempt to write (in a different process) to the same tty (as either `/proc/$pid/fd/0` or `/dev/pts/?` you accomplish exactly the same thing as the process itself does when it writes data to it's output; the data shows up in the terminal window.

Actually changing where fd[0-2] point after starting a process is fairly complicated, but not impossible. [Reptyr](http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/) is a free open source application that modifies an existing process so it's fd[0-2] point to a different tty (as well as some other stuff). This is accomplished through the *ptrace* framework. The post also mentions other softwares that do the same thing, and that it can be done through *gdb*.

Depending on what you actually wanted to accomplish, you might find Reptyr or some other software does what you need. Otherwise, you can look at/copy/modify the source code and find out how they do the trick.

**Addendum:**
[This](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) contains a few illustrating diagrams, in particular the [third](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/case3.png) schematic from the top.

Comment: So, tty actually reads from keyboard in a magical way, and writing anything to tty can only cause the display of messages.

Comment: Less magic and more "inside the kernel", but yes.

Answer (score 5):

Go to terminal A any type `tty`

you will get something like "/dev/pts/0"

Now, go to terminal B and type `exec 0</dev/pts/0` (or whatever the tty command gave you)

Return to terminal A and commands you enter will run on terminal B.

Comment: Let me mention that this creates an *interesting* race condition, which on my system makes it seemingly random which shell gets a character.

Comment: Eoren, that sounds like there are two reader for one input who are compete for the data from the same stream.

Answer (score 1):

> How to redirect to stdin of a running bash shell?

using C (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7370822. i have not tested it):

```
char* cmd="ls\n";
int fd = open (ptsname, O_RDWR);

while (*cmd)
{
    ioctl(fd, TIOCSTI, cmd++);
}
```

using Perl (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48221. works perfectly, but only for current shell):

```
require "sys/ioctl.ph";
ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV;
```

Comment: On superuser, we are talking about shell, not C or perl.