# Exchanging input data between shell scripts

Tags: linux, shell, android

I have a simple shell script to run in Android adb shell.

```
while true; do
    read var1
    echo $var1 > /data/local/tmp/debug.txt
    am force-stop $var1
done
```

It works ok if I enter a value in the console of original shell instance. But if I open another adb shell and try to pass data into the first process:

```
echo "com.package.name" > /proc/XXXX/fd/0
```

where XXXX is the pid of the first shell, I see only that the string "com.package.name" arrives into the first shell's `read`, but neither debug `echo` line, nor `am` line is executed. That is the script seems waiting for something, perhaps a newline char, but adding `\n`, `-e` argument, and other stuff into the second shell input did not help.

How do I properly pass data between shell scripts?

Comment: You are asking two similar/related, yet distinct, questions: (1) How can I exchange data between two scripts or programs (that I have written), and (2) How can command (or script/program) “B” provide input to script / program “A”, when “A” is just reading from the terminal/keyboard (in this case, in a different window) and isn’t expecting input from another process (and, therefore, isn’t doing anything special that would enable it to *receive* input from another process)?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Question 1 is fairly broad; [MariusMatutiae’s answer](http://superuser.com/a/1045482/150988) is a good start at answering it.  Question 2 is hard.  In general, it’s impossible.  If it were easy to do, it would be a security weakness, so it has been made difficult, and increasingly so over the years — some solutions that worked five or more years ago might not work on modern systems.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  This is a possible duplicate of [How to redirect to stdin of a running bash shell?](http://superuser.com/q/403148/150988).  (I can’t vote to close because it has an open bounty.)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  This has been asked several times on Stack Exchange: on Unix & Linux [here \[How do I run a command in a different tty?\]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/260503/23408) and [here \[Construct a command by putting a string into a tty\]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48103/23408); and on Stack Overflow [here \[Linux – write commands from one terminal to another\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10376251/1672723) and [here [Ask a running bash (interactive) to run a command from outside\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7370538/1672723).

Comment: @Scott, I'm just asking the question about the concrete task. Of course you are free to dissect it to some subtasks as you wish. Most of your references seems irrelevant, because I'm limited to android adb shell. But thank you anyway.

Comment: It's not an issue of subtasks, it's an issue of scope. Your last paragraph asks a question that's *much* broader in scope than the first *n-1* paragraphs (the title is somewhat ambiguous). It's as if you wrote a question asking about *driving* from New York to Florida, going into details like pre-trip car maintenance, variations in gasoline prices along the route, good places to stop and spend the night, etc., and then ended with a summary question, "What's the best way to get from New York to Florida?" And, of course, ***that*** question invites answers like "plane", "boat", "train" or "bus".

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I’m sorry if my references don’t help you — but, if a whole bunch of answers from Super User, Unix & Linux, and Stack Overflow aren’t relevant to your question, then that’s a red flag that your question isn’t relevant to those sites (i.e., it might be off-topic).  You might receive more attention at [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Speaking of references, see also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/195817) — I’m wondering whether you are trying to solve problem X = pass data between shell scripts (*get* to Florida) and you are asking about solution Y = have one process write directly to the standard input of an unsuspecting (unwilling) unrelated process (***drive*** to Florida).

Comment: @Scott, the last line in the question is not mine. Please, check the history of edits. You may remove it, if you think it makes the question hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You are being waylaid by the usual concept, that *everything in a Linux system is a file*. To illustrate this, I have put your commands in a file called `forever`, then found the PID of the process, then

```
$ file /proc/25546/fd/*
  /proc/25546/fd/0:   symbolic link to `/dev/pts/12' 
  /proc/25546/fd/1:   symbolic link to `/dev/pts/12' 
  /proc/25546/fd/2:   symbolic link to `/dev/pts/12' 
  /proc/25546/fd/255: symbolic link to `/home/me/tmp/forever'
 $ file /dev/pts/12
  /dev/pts/12: character special
```

This shows that your file descriptors 1,2,3 are character files. Now, it is well known (see for instance [this answer on Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60147/49626)) that:

> Character devices (also called character special files) behave like pipes, serial ports, etc: writing or reading to them is an immediate action. But what the driver does with the data is **its own business**. Writing a byte to a character device might cause it to be displayed on screen, output on a serial port, converted into a sound, ... Reading a byte from a device might cause the serial port to wait for input, might return a random byte (/dev/urandom), ...

So you need another way to perform IPC (=Inter Process Communication). **On Unix and on Linux**, there are  *named pipes* for this. Modify your script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

MYPIPE=/tmp/my_pipe
if [[ ! -p $MYPIPE ]]; then
     mkfifo $MYPIPE
fi

while true
do
     if read line <$pipe; then
         if [[ "$line" == 'quit' ]]; then
            break
         fi
         echo $line >> /tmp/debug.txt
     fi
done

echo "I quit"
```

Start the script; from another terminal type

```
 $ cat > /tmp/my_pipe
   My name is 
   George Washington 
    ....
```

From a third terminal, using `tail -f /tmp/debug.txt`, you will see what you just typed into the second terminal, reappear from `/tmp/debug.txt`.

**On Android**, the situation is a tad more complex, but you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2758038/2796243) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760267/2796243) two distinct ways around the problem of making named pipes on a non-rooted Android device (the first one is simpler than the second one).

Comment: shouldn't it be `cat > /tmp/my_pipe` rather than `cat /tmp/my_pipe`? Or am I just missing something that's different in this environment?

Comment: @dma1324 No, you got me. You are perfectly right, I corrected it. Thanks for spotting it.